# Displaying flatgeobuf file in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, flatgeobuf

I am trying to read flatgeobuf file (see https://flatgeobuf.org/examples/leaflet/) in Leaflet, but it returns blank.
Here is my code:

```
import './style.css'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css';
    
import L from 'leaflet'       
import * as flatgeobuf from 'flatgeobuf';

const map = L.map('map', {
  center: [35.50, -90],
  zoom: 5
});
   
var southWest = L.latLng(30.396308, -180),
  northEast = L.latLng(70.384358, -60.885444);
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  ext: 'png',
  minNativeZoom: 4,
  minZoom: 4,
  tms: false,
  bounds: bounds
}).addTo(map);
   
const response = await fetch('https://flatgeobuf.org/test/data/UScounties.fgb')
for await (const f of flatgeobuf.deserialize(response.body))
    L.geoJSON(f).addTo(map)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is nor really a GIS question, but completely JS related one, but anyway ... If you look at the browser debugger console, you should see an error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the
> top level bodies of modules

This is because you are using `await` outside `async` function/module. To make it work, just wrap your code in immediately-invoked function expression:

```
(async () => {
  // your code
})();
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/6knc1j0g/

Comment: Thanks, i tried to wrap the flatgeobuf in async `(async () => {const response = await fetch('https://flatgeobuf.org/test/data/UScounties.fgb')
for await (const f of flatgeobuf.deserialize(response.body))
  L.geoJSON(f).addTo(map)
})(); ` But still it displays blank

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console and/or network section?

Comment: This is the error 'TypeError: flatgeobuf.deserialize(...) is not a function or its return value is not async iterable'

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger network section?

Comment: it works when i import flatgeobuf through CDN directly in html. But, when I import the flatgeobuf module in the JS, i get the error. And no error in the network section. I think the error is with with the way i am importing. Also, flatgeobuf is written in typescript. Do you think importing typescript module in js has any effect ? Sorry for these rookies questions, I am still learning JS and leaflet.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with ES6 JS, I can't help you here. As I wrote, this is more a question for StackOverflow site.